# Android Studio JDK Path Error

Tags: java, android

I have installed the latest version of Android Studio as well as the latest version of Java Development Kit. I have followed the instructions on the Android Studio download page to create a environment variable JAVA_HOME and placed the JDK path in it. But when I launch Android Studio I get and error telling me to use a valid JDK path. So I go to the settings in Android Studio to verify that I have a valid JDK path which I do and click ok. But I still get the same error.

Comment: What is the path you gave?

Comment: This is the path I gave C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 sorry for the late response.